# The equation of motion in the central field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, symmetry

There is a central field $U(r)=\frac{kr^{2}}{2}$ (spatial oscillator,
$k > 0$), in which a particle of mass $m$ moves.
Describing the position of a particle in Cartesian coordinates $x, y, z$, construct the Lagrangian of the particle and its equations of motion. Solve
them.

I was able to make up the Lagrangian and proceed to consider the movement by coordinates:

$m\ddot{x}+kx=0$

The solution is the oscillator equation.

How can I prove that my trajectory is an ellipse and express the semi-axes in terms of energy and angular momentum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy is $E=\frac 12m|v|^2-k|r|^2$

Suppose you are in one of the semi-axis, in this case $|r|$ is the length of the semi-axis $s$.

since $r$ and $v$ are orthogonal in the semi-axis the angular momentum is $|L|=m|v||s|$, so $|v|=\frac{|L|}{m|s|}$

from now on we are working with all scalars, so we are going to drop the norm $|\cdot|$

So we get that

$E=\frac{L^2}{2ms^2} - ks^2$

Rearranging a bit we get

$ks^4+Es^2-\frac{L^2}{2m}=0$

which is a quadratic equation!

$s^2=\frac{-E\pm\sqrt{E^2+2L^2k/m}}{2k}$

The one with the plus sign is the square of the major semi-axis, and the one with the minus is the minor semi-axis

---

As far as proving that the trajectory is an ellipse you have to solve the equation of motion

$
\begin{cases}
x=A\cos (\omega t) - B\sin (\omega t)\\
y=B\sin (\omega t) + D\cos (\omega t)
\end{cases}
$

where $\omega^2=k/m$

In theory you could stop here, plot the thing and see it's an ellipse

If you actually want to prove there are some ways, the way I'm going to use is to use some linear algebra, so let's write se system above in matrix form

$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A\cos (\omega t) - B\sin (\omega t)\\
C\sin (\omega t) + D\cos (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
$

Where A,B,C,D depend on the initial conditions (they can also be negative, I have put a minus after the $B$ because it will be easier afterwards to do the calculations

we can write the last matrix as a product a new matrix which we are going to call $M'$ times a revolving unit vector

$
\begin{bmatrix}
A\cos (\omega t) - B\sin (\omega t)\\
C\sin (\omega t) + D\cos (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A' & B'\\
C' & D'
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\omega t) -\sin (\omega t)\\
\sin (\omega t) +\cos (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
$

The revolving vector represents the path along a circumference and the new matrix $M'$ represents a distortion, and a distorted circumference is a ellipse

Now you just have to prove that $M'$ exists, so you have two choices:

1-believe that it exists,

2-read the following proof

So, by doing the matrix multiplication on the right and now imposing the equality with the path of the original

$
\begin{bmatrix}
A' & B'\\
C' & D'
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (\omega t) -\sin (\omega t)\\
\sin (\omega t) +\cos (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(A'+C')\cos(\omega t) -(A'-C')\sin (\omega t)\\
(D'-B')\cos(\omega t) +(D'+B')\sin (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
$

And now you impose the equality with the equation of motion

$
\begin{bmatrix}
A\cos (\omega t) - B\sin (\omega t)\\
C\sin (\omega t) + D\cos (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
(A'+C')\cos(\omega t) -(A'-C')\sin (\omega t)\\
(D'-B')\cos(\omega t) +(D'+B')\sin (\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
$

It has to be equal for every $t$, so

$
\begin{cases}
A=A'+C'\\
B=A'-C'\\
C=D'-B'\\
D=D'+B'
\end{cases}
$

There you go, the matrix exists, this means that the trajectory is an ellipse

Comment: And how can I prove that my trajectory is really an ellipse in Cartesian coordinates through the Lagrange function?  I understand how to do this in polar coordinates

Comment: oh yes you are right, let me edit the answer